# In Kendo grid, how to avoid deep copy data sending to client side?

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, deep-copy

I have a model project in which there are a few [Foreignkey] attribute such as orders, users .... That is convenient to get more information in somewhere else. For example, I can get the users name easily using project.users.username.

Now there is question:

When I use the Telerik Kendo grid to list the project content by using

```
.Read(read=>read.Action("GetProjectData", "Project", new {projID = Model.projID}))
```

The function in server side like this:

```
public ActionResult GetProjectData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, long projID)
{
    var p = db.project.where(c=>c.projectID == projID);
    return Json(p.ToDataSourceResult(request))
}
```

the webpage is fine. It listed all the content of what I want. But when I debug the data that is sent from the server, I found the server sent a lot of extra data including a deep copy of the project data. All of the user information are in response package. I have some foreignkeys in the user model and those class data are there also. The data are huge.

Is there any way to let the sever just send the first layer data for the security and efficiency reason? I created a new class and just copied the needed data from project and send to client. Is there any simple way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, I'm guessing you are using Telerik FluentModel to access your data. Maybe you can use something like this, or this can help you:

```
Telerik.OpenAccess.FetchOptimization.FetchStrategy fetchStrategy = new Telerik.OpenAccess.FetchOptimization.FetchStrategy();
db.FetchStrategy = fetchStrategy;

var detachedCopy = db.CreateDetachedCopy<List<project>>(p.ToList(), fetchStrategy);
```

This should give you your initial lista w/o external properties. This link should help you too: http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/crud-operations/defining-fetch-plans/getting-started-root-getting-started-with-fetchplans

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `ScriptIgnoreAttribute`? This may do exactly what you are looking for. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute for documentation.